# Configure TestContainers with Springboot test

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, testcontainers

I was using embedded mysql to run SpringBootTest but now I am trying to replace it with TestContainers.But I am not able to figure out how can I convert below Entity Managers in TestContainers.

DB1EntityManager:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "requestEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "requestTransactionManager", basePackages = {"org.onap.so.db.request.data.repository"})
public class RequestDBEntityManager {
    @Bean(name = "requestEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("requestDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("org.onap.so.db.request.beans").persistenceUnit("requestDB")
                .build();
    }


    @Bean(name = "requestTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("requestEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

DB2EntityManager:-

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        basePackages = {"org.onap.so.db.catalog.data.repository"})
public class CatalogEntityManager {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("org.onap.so.db.catalog.beans").persistenceUnit("catalogDB")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

If I try to using below code in my test I get error:-

```
    @Testcontainers
    public class ServiceInstancesTest extends BaseTest {
         @Container
            @ServiceConnection
            static MySQLContainer<?> mysql = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.0");
    static MySQLContainer<?> mysql2 = new MySQLContainer<>("mysql:8.0");
    
    
            @DynamicPropertySource
            static void configureProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
                mysql.withUsername("XXXX");
                mysql.withDatabaseName("XXXX");
                mysql.withPassword("XXXX");
                mysql2.withUsername("XXXX");
                mysql2.withDatabaseName("XXXX");
                mysql2.withPassword("XXXX");// trying to use 2 dbs as I need both
            }
```

Error:-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'requestEntityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/onap/so/apihandlerinfra/RequestDBEntityManager.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'entityManagerFactory' parameter 1: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("requestDataSource")}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:550)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:560)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58)
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1406)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:545)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137)
        at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:119)
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:127)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockTestExecutionListener.applicationContextBroken(WireMockTestExecutionListener.java:120)
        at org.springframework.cloud.contract.wiremock.WireMockTestExecutionListener.afterTestClass(WireMockTestExecutionListener.java:58)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestClass(TestContextManager.java:487)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.afterAll(SpringExtension.java:122)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$18(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:461)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeAfterAllCallbacks$19(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:461)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeAfterAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:461)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:235)
        at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.after(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:161)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
        at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
        at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Please let me know how can I transform my code properly to use multiple databases where I can reuse my testcontainers and convert the EntityManagers correctly.